# Why is my command line echoed?

Tags: windows, cmd

I wrote the following command line.

`C:\Users\Administrator> echo TOMATO:50EA| (set /p z=& call set v1=APPLE:30EA %z%& for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %K in ('echo %v1%') do (echo Item 1: %K ,  Item 2: %L))`

**Result:**

> ```
> C:\Users\Administrator>(echo Item 1: APPLE:30EA ,  Item 2: TOMATO:50EA )
> Item 1: APPLE:30EA ,  Item 2: TOMATO:50EA
> ```

Why has it also printed the `echo` command line?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour in command line is to echo to console the command that will be executed. You can turn echo off or precede the commands you want to hide with `@`

```
echo TOMATO:50EA|(set /p z=& for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %K in ('echo APPLE:30EA %z%') do @echo Item 1: %K , Item 2: %L)
```

But this code (and your code) has a point of failure. It will only work while `z` has no value before starting to execute the command.

You can try to use delayed expansion

```
echo TOMATO:50EA|cmd /q /v /c"(set /p z=& for /F "tokens=1,2" %K in ("APPLE:30EA !z!") do echo Item 1: %K , Item 2: %L)"
```

and while the default configuration (with delayed expansion disabled) is used, then this code will solve the problem. But if you have delayed expansion enabled at command line and `z` has an initial value it will also fail.

**Note:**
The code in the question is written using `%K`. This means command line. Remember that in batch files the `for` replaceable parameters need to have the percent sign escaped (`%%K`).